# MediaWiki VisualEditor Installation on a shared hosting

Tags: editor, hosting, mediawiki, shared

Tutorial for installing visual editor of MediaWiki on a shared hosting is not updated on their website.
[MediaWiki Visual Installation Guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor/Installation_on_a_shared_host)
May be it has been written for an old version of localhostsettings.js because it doesn't match with the current one.

**Form MediaWiki Site, they say:**

```
Open localsettings.example.js, and change parsoidConfig.setMwApi according to your wiki:
    The first parameter is the "prefix". The "prefix" is the name given to this wiki configuration in the deprecated Parsoid v1 API - Leave this option as default 'localhost'.
    The second parameter is "domain". The "domain" is used for communication with Visual Editor and RESTBase - Leave this optoin as default 'localhost'.
    The third parameter is "uri". The "uri" is the URL to your API (normally this is in the root-folder and called api.php) - Change this option according your wiki (For example http://wiki.example.com/api.php or http://example.com/w/api.php or something like that).
    "Proxy" parameter leave as default.
    If you use SSL on your wiki with a self-signed certificate you should uncomment parsoidConfig.strictSSL = false; in Line 102. You should still use HTTP in the URL above instead of HTTP! Note that, in at-least one instance for a Wiki on SSL having redirect rules for HTTP to HTTPS, using http://example.com/w/api.php instead of https://example.com/w/api.php gave an: "Error loading data from server: 500:docserver-http:HTTP 500." error. This was fixed on using https:// or on removing the redirect rule.
```

But it doesn't match. Can anyone please explain what settings should I need to change to get it running?

Comment: This should probably go in ServerFault.